# a json telegram bot response always showing up after i submit the form , i want to just alert it using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, telegram-bot

I wanted to send photo from this HTML to a group in telegram using a bot, then I found this code in this forum it works fine but after I submit the form, the browser opening a new tab then showing up a JSON response

what I want after I submit the form is just `alert('photo has been sent!')`

what should I do?

```
<form method="POST" target="_blank"
action="https://api.telegram.org/bot{{ config('app.token') }}/sendPhoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="chat_id" value="{{ config('app.idgroup') }}" hidden />
<input type="text" name="reply_to_message_id" value="{{ $rp->msg_id }}" hidden />
<input type="text" name="allow_sending_without_reply" value="true" hidden />
<br />
<label for="caption"> Caption</label>
<input type="text" name="caption" placeholder="caption" />
<br />
<input type="file" name="photo" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="sendPhoto" />
</form>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: you are using target blank to submit the form. that is causing the new tab issue. and to get the response and alert it, i would suggest you to use javascript to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```